# Span<long> operations return “cannot convert long to int”

Tags: c#

I’m a bit new to the finer .Net operations (Unity programmer), so I can’t figure out why the compiler thinks that a `Span<long>` created from a `long[]`, and iterated upon with a simple add operation (`mySpan[index] += value`), is trying to cast to an int somewhere. index and value are both of type long. Is this a compiler issue?
Code segment below.

````
 long[] zeroes = new long[n];
  long amount = 1000000;  //placeholder; can be longer
Span<long> segment = zeroes.AsSpan<long>(); 
            
            for(long j=startIndex; j <= endIndex; j++)
            {   
                
                segment[j] += amount;
            }```
...
````

Comment: Would help to include the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> index and value are both of type long. Is this a compiler issue?

No; [the indexer on `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` expects `int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.item?view=net-6.0); if you have `long index` and use `mySpan[index]`, it will need to cast `long` to `int`, which is not a valid implicit cast. Either make `index` an `int`, or use `mySpan[(int)index]` (but  maybe think about what might happen if this overflows in an unchecked context).